# how to setup the first 2 bytes on a java UDP Datagram Packet?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I have a client-server program trying to send a jpg file.

I'm trying to add an ACKNOWLEDGE byte and the DATA's BlockNumber byte to a UDP packet. I'm having trouble in this part of the code (this section of the code is just the DATA Block handling code from the Client program):

```
if(pType == TftpUtil.DATA){     //If byte 0 = 2 meaning it's a DATA block.

    private int blockNumber = 1;    

    byte[] bn = intToBytes(blockNumber);        
    
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);   // For 2 ints, an int is 4 bytes long
    buff.put(TftpUtil.ACK);                     // This is an "ACKNOWLEDGE byte", at position zero.
    buff.put(bn);                               // This is supposed to be a byte containing the integer "blockNumber" meaning, what DATA block in the series it is.
    buff.rewind();                              // Not sure what this does. What does this do? Saw it in the code I copied. 
    DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(buff.array(), buff.limit(), echoServerIP, 69);   //Create datagramPacket

    System.out.println("TftpClient sending a ACK on port " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());
    clientSocket.send(dataPacket);
    blockNumber++;
    
}
```

The above code doesn't work with the server I have, and the server was made by the Teacher. I've checked the server code, looks great.

For some reason it hangs on the part where it's supposed to send an ACKNOWLEDGE byte that contains the integer, "3" meaning "Acknowledged". And it's supposed to contain that ACK byte in position zero of the buff.array(). But the server says there's no acknowledge byte being received.

TftpUtil starts off like this:

```
public class TftpUtil {
    
    //read request packet 
    public static final byte RRQ = 1;
    //data packet
    public static final byte DATA = 2;
    //ack packet
    public static final byte ACK = 3;
    //error packet
    public static final byte ERROR = 4;
    //the maximum number of resent
    public static final int MAX_RESEND = 5;     
    //data buffer size: 512
    public static int DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
    //packet buffer size: 2 bytes header + 512 bytes file data;
    public static int PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE = DATA_BUFFER_SIZE + 2;  
}
```

What the server's doing is it's sending a .jpg file, in DATA blocks of 512 bytes. The server picks up that there's a connection made, and tries to send the file. It sends the first DATA block, which seems to come through because when I check the folder, there is an asd.jpg file of 512 bytes. But when the client goes to send the ACK byte back, the server says it's incorrect and times out.

Can you see what's wrong with the code I've pasted or should I paste more code?

Thanks.

**UPDATE** full server code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class server_v004 {
    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;
    private DatagramSocket serverSocket; 
    private static final ExecutorService exec =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
    
    public void startServer()
    {
        try {
            String serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.32";
            InetAddress echoServerIP = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort, echoServerIP);
            System.out.println("TftpServer on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
    
            while(true) {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1472];
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buf, 1472);
                System.out.println("waiting for connection ....");
                serverSocket.receive(p);            
                server_v004ServerWorker worker = new server_v004ServerWorker(p);
                exec.execute(worker);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        serverSocket.close();
        return;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        server_v004 tftpServer = new server_v004();
        //tftpServer.checkArgs(args);
        try{
            tftpServer.parseArgsAndInit(args);
            tftpServer.startServer();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }

    private void checkArgs(String[] args){
         if(args.length <0) {       //<1    //<2     
             System.out.println("Usage: TftpServer");       //server_port server_ip
             System.exit(0);
         }
    }
    
    private void parseArgsAndInit(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);           
        serverPort = 12345;         //Integer.parseInt(args[1]);                    
   }    
}

class server_v004ServerWorker implements Runnable
{
    //use to store RRQ request
    private DatagramPacket req;
    //client address who sent the RRQ request 
    private SocketAddress clientAddress;
    //socket used to send the file data packets to client
    private DatagramSocket sendfileSocket;
    //byte buffer to store the file data
    private byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[TftpUtil.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
    //the first block sequence
    private byte currentBlockSeq = 1;
    //use to retrieve the ack packet, only two bytes long
    private DatagramPacket ackDP = new DatagramPacket(new byte[2], 2);
    private int TIME_OUT = 1000; //1 second 
    
    
    public void run(){
        try{
            sendfileSocket = new DatagramSocket(69);
            System.out.println("TftpServer sending a file on port " + sendfileSocket.getLocalPort());
            byte pType = TftpUtil.checkPacketType(req);
            clientAddress = req.getSocketAddress();
            //checking if the first packet from client is a RRQ packet 
            if(pType == TftpUtil.RRQ){
                String filename = getFileName(req);
                System.out.println("Requested file name:" + filename);
                //if the file doesn't exist, send ERROR packet and close socket
                if(!(new File(filename)).exists()) {
                    DatagramPacket errorDP = TftpUtil.packErrorPacket(filename);
                    errorDP.setSocketAddress(clientAddress);
                    sendfileSocket.send(errorDP);
                }
                else{
                    //the file does exist, send file
                    sendfile(filename);
                }
            }// end if
        
        }catch(Exception e){        
                e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        sendfileSocket.close(); 
        return;
    }

     
    private void sendfile(String filename) throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(filename);                     
        while(true){
          int rec = fileInput.read(dataBuffer);
          //the file size is a multiple of 512, send empty packet 
          if(rec == -1){
                 sendDataPacket(new byte[0],0);
                 System.out.println("The last packet [0 byte in size]:#"+currentBlockSeq);
                 break;
            }   
            //send a file data packet
            boolean successed = sendDataPacket(dataBuffer,rec);
           //tried five times
           if (!successed) {
                System.out.println("Tried five times, give up");
                System.exit(0);
           }
           // the last packet (the file size if not a multiple of 512)
           if (rec < 512 && rec > 0 ) {
               System.out.println("The last packet ["+rec+" bytes in size]:#"+currentBlockSeq);
                    break; 
           }
           currentBlockSeq++;       
        }//while
        fileInput.close();
    }
    
     //
    private  boolean sendDataPacket(byte[] databuffer,int length) throws Exception{
        int resendCount = 0;
    
        DatagramPacket dataPacket = packFileDataPacket(databuffer,length);
        //try five times
        while(resendCount < TftpUtil.MAX_RESEND){
          try{
                  sendfileSocket.send(dataPacket); 
                  sendfileSocket.setSoTimeout(TIME_OUT);
              System.out.println("sent data block #"+currentBlockSeq+", waiting for ack #" + currentBlockSeq);
              //ack arrives
              sendfileSocket.receive(ackDP);
              byte ackedBlockseq = TftpUtil.extractACKNumber(ackDP);
              System.out.println("received ack #" + ackedBlockseq);
             if(ackedBlockseq != currentBlockSeq) {
                  //the acked block seq is not the seq of block sent
                  //ignore this ack and resend                             
                       resendCount++; 
                       continue;
                   } 
                //this data packet has been acked, return
                return true; 
        
             }//end of try
             catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){
                    resendCount++;
                System.out.println("timeout #" + resendCount );
             }
         }//end of while
    
        return false;   
    }
      
    private DatagramPacket packFileDataPacket(byte[] dataBuffer, int length){
        int packetLength = 2 + length;//type (1) + block seq (1) + data length
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packetLength); 
        byteBuffer.put(TftpUtil.DATA);//type
        byteBuffer.put(currentBlockSeq);//block seq
        byteBuffer.put(dataBuffer,0,length);//data   
        DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(byteBuffer.array(), packetLength);
        dataPacket.setSocketAddress(clientAddress);
        return  dataPacket; 
    }
     
    private  String getFileName(DatagramPacket dataDP){  
        byte[] data = dataDP.getData();
        int dataLength = dataDP.getLength();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataLength-1); 
        //remove the packet type (RRQ)
        byteBuffer.put(data,1,dataLength-1);
        return new String(byteBuffer.array());
    }

    public server_v004ServerWorker(DatagramPacket req)
    {
        this.req = req;
    }
}
```

and full TftpUtil code:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class TftpUtil {
    
    //read request packet 
    public static final byte RRQ = 1;
    //data packet
    public static final byte DATA = 2;
    //ack packet
    public static final byte ACK = 3;
    //error packet
    public static final byte ERROR = 4;
    //the maximum number of resent
    public static final int MAX_RESEND = 5;     
    //data buffer size: 512
    public static int DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
    //packet buffer size: 2 bytes header + 512 bytes file data;
    public static int PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE = DATA_BUFFER_SIZE + 2;  
    
    //return the type (RRQ, DATA, ACK or ERROR) of a packet  
    public static byte checkPacketType(DatagramPacket dataDP){
            byte[] payload = dataDP.getData();      
            return payload[0];
      }
     
     //return a RRQ packet 
    public static DatagramPacket packRRQDatagramPacket(byte[] filename) throws Exception{
        return packDatagramPacket(RRQ, filename);   
    }   
    
    //return a "file not found" error packet
    public static DatagramPacket packErrorPacket(String filename) throws Exception{
        String errorMessage = filename + " not found";
        return packDatagramPacket(ERROR, errorMessage.getBytes());
    }
    
    /*
     * utility method that wrap a packet type, data into a DatagramPacket
     */
    private static DatagramPacket packDatagramPacket(byte type, byte[] payload) throws Exception{
        int dataLength = 1 + payload.length;
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataLength); 
        byteBuffer.put(type);
        byteBuffer.put(payload);    
        return new DatagramPacket(byteBuffer.array(), dataLength);      
     }  
    
    //return the ack number of a ACK packet
    public static  byte extractACKNumber(DatagramPacket ackDP){
            byte[] payload = ackDP.getData();
            return payload[1];
    }
    
    //print the string content of a ERROR packet 
    public static void printErrorString(DatagramPacket p){
           byte[] data = p.getData();
           int dataLength = p.getLength();
           ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataLength-1);
           //ignore the packet type
           byteBuffer.put(data,1, dataLength-1);
          System.out.print(new String(byteBuffer.array()));
        }
  
    //return the block sequence of a data packet
    public static byte extractBlockSeq(DatagramPacket dataDP){
        byte[] payload = dataDP.getData();
        if(payload.length <=1) return -1; //-1: no block sequence in data
        int type = payload[0];
        if(type == DATA){
            return payload[1];
        }
        return -1; //-1: not a data packet
       
   }
    
}
```

Comment: We could probably use that server code, just to see what is actually expected.  We could also use the error message that gets produced.  To debug this, set up both the client and the server on your own machine so you can watch what both ends do.  You need to see both or you're just guessing what the actual problem is.

Comment: I can see both and do run it locally. Am I meant to be using wireshark, would that be useful?

Comment: If it works locally, you should talk to your teacher.  The problem might be on his or her end.  Can you find error paths that the server might be taking?  What error messages might the server produce?  Where can you find those errors?

Comment: Oh, speaking of local vs remote: this is UDP.  Are you sure the packet is reaching the server?  Running Wireshark on the server side might be a good idea if there's any chance these packets are just being dropped.

Comment: They're both on the same IP address, bouncing packets between socket 69 (server) and another random socket (client).